# How to grab value of pre and put in input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the value of the pre tag.  I inserted the value based upon a drop down into the pre tag. How would I grab the content of the `<pre>` and put it into the `<input>`? I can grab the content, but am struggling setting it as value for the `<input>`. Below, I have an example of what I have done.

JQUERY

```
             var $temp = $('#Changeinfo').text();
             alert($temp);
             $('#Details') = $temp;
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="Details">Details</label>
            <div contenteditable="false" name="DetailID" id="DetailID"><pre 
  value="26" id="Changeinfo"> Do this based on selection

    </pre>
  </div>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Details" name="Details" value="">
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Details" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: using jQuery: `$('#Details').val($temp);` Vanilla JS: `document.getElementById('Details').value = $temp;`

Comment: I could probably go on, but I think the point is made :)

Comment: $('#Details').val($('#Changeinfo').attr('value')); Is what I used. Thank you!